# Export PDF graphics without shape contours and filling areas becoming separated

Tags: pdf, imagemagick-convert, vector-graphics

I have encountered this issue with numerous PDF figures (the figures themselves are PDFs embedded in PDFs):

In the PDF viewer the figure looks nice, shapes such as circles and arrowheads are solid, with the contour and fill areas not being separated.

Here is an example: [pdf](http://chymera.eu/debug/pdf_shapes/slides.pdf)

I have tried converting the pages to images via either:

#### (A)

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=slides_.pdf slides.pdf &&\
convert -density 900 slides_.pdf -scale 3840x2160 output.png
```

#### (B)

```
convert -density 600 slides.pdf -scale 3840x2160 output.png
```

Via both approaches I get images where vector shapes have a jagged layer of pixels separating the fill and contours of shapes. This can best be seen in the full-resolution view of the 8th page:

[image]

Any ideas how I can prevent this? E.g. in the page shared above, I would like for the arrowheads and the filled white circle in the upper left to be of one solid color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue is the imagemagick conversion library. I was unable to fix this issue by tweaking the `convert` parameters, but I could solve it by using another library --- more specifically, poppler.

```
pdftoppm -png -scale-to-y 2160 -scale-to-x 3840 slides.pdf output
```

Produced exactly what I was looking for.